# Android Instrumental Test not starting with Startup library

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Using Hilt and Startup together. Application is starting without problems, but instrumented test cannot, just infinite waiting.

After disabling `androidx.startup.InitializationProvider` in `Manifest.xml` tests are starting well. Also looks like troubles are in initializers with EntryPoint injection like:

```
class SomeLibraryInitializer : Initializer<SomeLibrary> {

    @Inject
    lateinit var someLibrary: SomeLibrary

    override fun create(context: Context): SomeLibrary {
        InitializerEntryPoint.resolve(context).inject(this)
        return someLibrary
    }

    override fun dependencies(): List<Class<out Initializer<*>>> = listOf(WorkManagerInitializer::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this?